# How to disable vars_prompt for skipped plays?

Tags: ansible

I am having a play "partial_upgrade.yml" that has vars_prompt to prompt the user for input.

I am importing this playbook in another playbook "choose_play.yml" which imports based on condition.

Even though  the "partial_upgrade.yml " is skipped it prompts for user input.

```
1. choose_play.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "option"
      prompt: |
         >>> 1. Partial Upgrade
         >>> 2. Full Upgrade
         >>> Enter the option which you want to run -
      private: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        option: "{{ option }}"
    - debug:
        var: option

- import_playbook: partial_upgrade.yml
  vars:
    partial_upgrade: true
    full_upgrade: false
  when: hostvars["localhost"]["option"]|int == 1

- import_playbook: full-upgrade.yml
  vars:
    partial_upgrade: false
    full_upgrade: true
  when: hostvars["localhost"]["option"]|int == 2


2. deploy.yml
---
- hosts: nodes
  gather_facts: false
  sudo: true
  vars_prompt:
     - name: "server_ip"
       prompt: "Enter Server IP"
       private: no

     - name: "server_path"
       prompt: "Enter Server path"
       private: no

  roles:
    - setup-master
    - setup-worker
```

When I run the "choose_play.yml" and press 2 then it skips the "partial_upgrade.yml" but prompts for "Server IP" and "Server Path".

I don't want to enter the details for the skipped play.

Please help me to disable the vars_prompt when the play is skipped.

Comment: Can you provide a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?